# Filtering some values with a value in a cell - VBA

Tags: filter

I'm spending a lot of time to find a solution to the following trouble, maybe you could help me;

- Data to be filtered `(A1:C20)`, contained in the sheet called (`Sheet1`). Row 1, is the header line.
- The criteria to filter are contained in `Sheet2` and the range is `(E3:F4)`, where the column `E` is the header line. `F3` as a format is a Date and the `F4` is a text.
  -In the `Sheet1`, the criteria `F3` (first criteria) corresponds to the column number 18 and the second criteria to column number 8.

I'd like to change these two criteria by hand to filter automatically the values.I built a macro but the problem, in my opinion, is the format of my criteria cells.

Any suggestions for this? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Filtra()
Sheets("CXL Data").Select
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$U$2500").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:= _
    "Physical Index"
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=1
Range("R2").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$U$2500").AutoFilter Field:=18, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues,**Criteria2:=Array(1, "11/1/2019")**
Columns("B:B").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Monthly Ventures").Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "STOCK CRUDE"
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select

Sheets("CXL Data").Select
Rows("1:1").Select
Range("B1").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.AutoFilter

Sheets("Gasoline Exposure").Select
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Sheets("Crude Exposure").Select
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Sheets("Gasoline Exposure").Select
```

End Sub

The criteria 2 is the criteria of which I'm speaking about.